# Unable to connect to bluetooth Health Device Fora using Android BluetoothProfile

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

I want to connect to Fora thermometer via Android BluetoothPRofile and get the reading.
Following is my approoach :-

1. In OnCreate() i have written this piece of code :-

   ```
   if (!mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mBluetoothServiceListener,
           BluetoothProfile.HEALTH)) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "No Health Profile Supported",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       return;
   }
   ```
2. This triggers the mBluetoothServiceListener callback which is mentioned below :-

   ```
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   private final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mBluetoothServiceListener =
   new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
   public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {

       Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected to profile: " + profile + " while health is " + BluetoothProfile.HEALTH);
       if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH) {
           mBluetoothHealth = (BluetoothHealth) proxy;
           if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
               Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected to profile: " + profile);
       }
       else if(profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
       {
           Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected to profile: " + profile);
       }
   }

   public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
       if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH) {
           mBluetoothHealth = null;
       }
   }
   };
   ```
3. After this the code searches for nearby bluetooth devices and shows it in the list.
   The onclicklistener of that list item calls the following code :-

   ```
   boolean bool = mBluetoothHealth.registerSinkAppConfiguration(TAG, HEALTH_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE, mHealthCallback);

   // where HEALTH_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE = 0x1008 (it's a body thermometer)
   ```
4. Once the registeration process is done i try to connect the device like this :-

   ```
       boolean bool = mBluetoothHealth.connectChannelToSource(mDevice, mHealthAppConfig);
   ```
5. Once all the above steps are done then the BluetoothHealthCallback is called whenever
   the device connection state changes

   ```
           private final BluetoothHealthCallback mHealthCallback = new BluetoothHealthCallback() {
   // Callback to handle application registration and unregistration events.  The service
   // passes the status back to the UI client.
   public void onHealthAppConfigurationStatusChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
           int status) {
       if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_FAILURE) {
           mHealthAppConfig = null;
       } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
           mHealthAppConfig = config;
       } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_FAILURE ||
               status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
       }
   }

   // Callback to handle channel connection state changes.
   // Note that the logic of the state machine may need to be modified based on the HDP device.
   // When the HDP device is connected, the received file descriptor is passed to the
   // ReadThread to read the content.
   public void onHealthChannelStateChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
           BluetoothDevice device, int prevState, int newState, ParcelFileDescriptor fd,
           int channelId) {
       if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
           Log.d(TAG, String.format("prevState\t%d ----------> newState\t%d",
                   prevState, newState));
       if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED &&
               newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
           if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
               mChannelId = channelId;

               (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
           } else {

           }
       } else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING &&
               newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {

       } else if (newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {
           if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {

           } else {

           }
       }
   }
       };
   ```

In the above case i get the BluetoothHealthCallback precisely 2 times :-

1. First Time i get the prevState = BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED and 
   newState = BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING
2. While in Second time i get the prevState = BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING and 
   newState = BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED

i.e. the attempt is made to connect to the device but it is not succesfull. 
Also in both the callbacks the ParcelFileDescriptor is null

*Note : The device is already paired

Comment: Seems that this uses Classic Bluetooth and not Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: Right... i guess somebody edited it. I will edit it again

Answer (score 1):

Do you think yours below "if" statement is right?

> if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED &&
>               newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {

It should be either (as it happen for classic Bluetooth devices)

> if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING &&
>               newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {

as you get connecting first and then connected

or I could be just

> if (newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {

And same correction for other "if" statement.

Also,
Does device support **paired and connected** option? If yes then you may try to **connect** it manually.