# Android connecting and disconnecting to health device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

i am creating an app to read the pulse measure from the health device (TaiDoc) via android Bluetooth using this[sample project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BluetoothHDP) of google.

this problem is same as to this  question asked  [Unable to connect to bluetooth Health Device Fora using Android BluetoothProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809749/unable-to-connect-to-bluetooth-health-device-fora-using-android-bluetoothprofile])[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809749/unable-to-connect-to-bluetooth-health-device-fora-using-android-bluetoothprofile)

which i tried the same and did not try to figure out.

**the below code of which check the connection state**

```
private final BluetoothHealthCallback mHealthCallback = new BluetoothHealthCallback() {
// Callback to handle application registration and unregistration events.     The service
// passes the status back to the UI client.
public void onHealthAppConfigurationStatusChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
    int status) {
if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_FAILURE) {
    mHealthAppConfig = null;
} else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
    mHealthAppConfig = config;
} else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_FAILURE ||
        status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
}
}

// Callback to handle channel connection state changes.
// Note that the logic of the state machine may need to be modified based on the HDP device.
// When the HDP device is connected, the received file descriptor is passed to the
// ReadThread to read the content.
public void onHealthChannelStateChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
    BluetoothDevice device, int prevState, int newState, ParcelFileDescriptor fd,
    int channelId) {
if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("prevState\t%d ----------> newState\t%d",
            prevState, newState));
if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED &&
        newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) {
    if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {
        mChannelId = channelId;

        (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
    } else {

    }
} else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING &&
        newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {

} else if (newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) {
    if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) {

    } else {

    }
}
}
};
```

**Problem**

I get 2 callbacks in BluetoothHealthCallback under onHealthChannelStateChange.

1. when prevState is =0 and newState = 1  (From disconnected to connecting).
2. when prevState is =1 and newState = 0  (From connecting to disconnected).

which means The device is not being connected or not reading the device

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue, did you able fix this issue, if so please add an answer. did you set any time or timeout while connecting using HDP

Comment: Hello, Whats your device?

Comment: I am using weighing scale

Comment: What is the weight scale brand?

Comment: its a philips device, did you try setting a time or timeout before connecting to an HDP device

Comment: is it Philips DL8780 ?

Comment: I used their SDK

Comment: Its not Philips DL8780

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144805/discussion-between-evan-and-naz141).